# C# DataAdapter can´t seem to update my MySQL Table

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, dataadapter

I´m trying to get my DataAdapter to update/insert new values to my table from another database (same table but different values) It should just copy the values from DB1 and insert/update them in DB2. I´m getting no compilation errors and the DataTables seems to have the correct values. But nothing gets updated or inserted.

So it should Fill a Datatable (dataTable1) from my database (DB1),
then set all rows to be modified and insert them into DB2
But, it wont work.

```
    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable("counters");
    string command = "SELECT * FROM counters;"; // same layout and name on both tables

    using (MySqlConnection connectionFrom = new MySqlConnection(constringfrom)) // DB1
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, connectionFrom);
        dataAdapter1.Fill(dataTable1);
    } 

    using (MySqlConnection ConnectionTo = new MySqlConnection(constringto)) // DB2
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, ConnectionTo);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cmb2 = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter2);
        dataAdapter2.UpdateCommand = cmb2.GetUpdateCommand();
        dataAdapter2.InsertCommand = cmb2.GetInsertCommand();
        foreach (DataRow r in dataTable1.Rows)
        {
            r.SetModified(); // just for testing purposes..
        }

        dataAdapter2.Update(dataTable1); // Correct values but no update to the DB :(
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Updating..... DONE"); // well... no
```

Comment: You aren't making any changes. What is there to update?

Comment: The values from dataTable1 is different from the values in dataTable2, that is the change, i want DB1 to continuously update DB2

Comment: The rows are *new* as far as the target database is concerned. You can try calling `SetAdded` instead of `SetModified`. Bear in mind though that DataAdapter was created to simplify binding to forms.

Comment: That only works one time (if the target DB is empty) then it crashes on trying to Add primary key duplicate

Comment: Obviously. Modified means you need to update, not insert. Added means you want to insert, not update. DataAdapters don't do upserts because they don't need to - when binding to a form you always know if a row is new or modified (also upsertss didn't exist back in 2002). If you want to update some rows but insert others, you 'll have to detect which is which and use the appropriate method. Or don't use DataAdapters - load the data with a datareader and execute an `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` for each individual row